# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI with Azure Mysql

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, azure-mysql-database

I have a python application with flask but I can't connect to the mysql database that is on Azure.

My config.py

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@mysqlsvr:pass1234@mysqlsvr.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/flask_db'

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the certificate and it worked

Follow

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@mysqlsvr:pass1234@mysqlsvr.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/flask_db?ssl_ca=BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'

Comment: This is the best answer ofther this forum... Thanks